# How do I seal the bottom of this door to be waterproof?

Tags: doors, waterproofing, door-frame

I'm going to be replacing this front door with a new prehung exterior steel frame door (pic available upon request).

[image: Door in question]

This door leads to a concrete porch and water tends to flow towards the door.  The door leaks around the bottom, and water drains into the basement area below the door.  This has caused 3 joists to completely rot through (already replaced) and when I replace the door I want to prevent this from happening again - at least as much as possible.

This is the bottom of the door from the inside
[image]

and outside
[image]

with closeups (L to R)
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have pictures of the basement area as well but I doubt those are useful.  I was thinking of replacing the wood and simply generously applying a LOT of sealant caulk (maybe something like used for sealing between concrete and patios rather than just plain silicon)... but I'm not sure.

Recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"water tends to flow towards the door" is your problem. The right way to fix this is to redo the exterior so water will flow away from the house. Sealing the gap would be a good secondary action, but if you leave it at that, you'll constantly be dealing with leaks.

Comment: Is it feasible to put a skim coat of concrete on top of the existing porch concrete to push water the other way?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be much vertical space between the top of the concrete and the door, so you might be restricted in how much you can do. Other options include adding a drain to catch and redirect water to a better location, and covering the area to prevent water from ending up there in the first place.

Comment: I'm struggling with a related situation and after discussing lots of ideas with contractors, putting a drain to catch water from the low spot and send it somewhere safer seems to be the best bet.